# Javascript keyup doesn't work as expected, it executes in instances where I have not removed my finger from a button

Tags: javascript, keypress, keydown, onkeyup

I'm trying to create a simple game in javascript and I'm stuck on how to deal with keys.

Small example:

```
function keyUpEvent(event) {
    alert(event.keyCode);
}
window.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpEvent, false);
```

I'm running Ubuntu 9.10 and testing it in Firefox 3.5 and Chromium.

If I press and release a button instantly I get an alert, which is to be expected, but when I press and hold a button I get a small pause and then a series of alert windows, the expected result is that I only get an alert window when I remove my finger from a button.

I reason it has something to do with the fact that when I press and hold a button in a text area for example I get one character, small pause, and then a series of characters: dddddddddddddddd.

I believe it's possible to get around this or do it more right or whatever since this game for example: http://bohuco.net/testing/gamequery/pong.html seams not to be affected by this. But I notice if I try out the jquery keyup demo ( api.jquery.com/keyup/ ) I get the same problem.

How can I implement basic game key event handling?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/keyup/ works fine for me in FF3.6 and Chrome under Vista - a keyup event is recognised only when I release a key and keeping a key pressed fires no keyup event. Are you 100% sure you're not accidentally catching keypress events? Keypress events are identical to the behaviour you describe.

Comment: I think theres a problem with this in ubuntu and maybe general in linux. Look i have a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254034/javascript-jquery-how-to-prevent-function-from-repeatedly-executed-when-holding-d

Answer (score 0):

The [example that you give](http://bohuco.net/testing/gamequery/pong.html), have the solution - why not follow it ?

Its use a timer after keyDown, and its not call direct the function that do the job. And this is the trick, you must use a timer.

Here is a [similar problem that can give you one more idea.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627339/async-trigger-for-an-update-panel-refreshes-entire-page-when-triggering-too-much/2627402#2627402)