# Javascript/JQuery How to prevent function from repeatedly executed when holding down key?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress, jquery-events, onkeyup

Let suppose we have the following JQuery Code:

```
$(document).bind('keyup', function(e) {    
    arrows=((e.which)||(e.keyCode));    
    switch (arrows){    
       case 37:
          executeMyfunction();     
          break;    
    }    
});
```

If a user holds down the left arrow key (37) the `executeMyfunction()` is repeatedly called.

How can I prevent this from happening?

I thought `keyup` would trigger only if key is released but its not working (that's why I use `keyup`; `keydown` does not work either).

Comment: could you set up a jsfiddle.net to show this?

Comment: This works as expected for me: http://jsfiddle.net/VMvcT/

Comment: @loannis Hm, your TAB key must be broken `:)`

Comment: @loannis Afaik, keydown and keypress will fire repeatedly, keyup will not.

Comment: @loaniss Your `arrows` variable has to be declared!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to unbind the event. I think it should not be `keyup`, but `keypress` or `keydown`.

Probably something like this.

```
$(document).bind('keydown', function(e) {    
    arrows=((e.which)||(e.keyCode));    
    switch (arrows){    
       case 37:    
          executeMyfunction();    
          $(document).unbind('keydown');    
          break;    
    }
});
```

You will have to rebind the function on `keyup` if you want to use the event again:

```
$(document).bind('keyup', function(e) {        
    switch (arrows){    
      case 37:
         $(document).bind('keydown');
         break;
    }    
})
```

Look at:
http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Comment: Look at this question, its the same problem, i also use ubuntu http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752524/javascript-keyup-doesnt-work-as-expected-it-executes-in-instances-where-i-have

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can always [debounce](http://unscriptable.com/index.php/2009/03/20/debouncing-javascript-methods/) the call to your function. That is, if you want your function to be called after the event has not been fired for a short period of time.